# Issuing jwt token if the user is successfully login via instagram

Tags: android, laravel, android-studio, jwt, instagram

I want to issues a jwt token to my server when a user successfully login to my mobile app. But the point is how to verify if the token is valid. There is not token verification system for Instagram to see whether he is the right user or not as facebook or google does.

What if a non-user sends a random verification code to the server?

I am using laravel as a webserver and Sanctum to issue jwt tokens

And user login from an Android App